# Using equals method in the conditional expression

Tags: java, conditional-statements, equals

Why does this conditional statement not work??
o1 and o2 are two different objects.

`o1.equals(o2) ? System.out.println("Objects are equal"): System.out.println("Objects are not equal");`

Comment: "Not work"? How do you define "work"? What types of objects are o1 and o2? How are their equal methods implemented?

Comment: While `o1` and `o2` may be different instances, they may be logically equal

Comment: @jontejj: o1 and o2 are objects of a class Obj with an integer instance variabl and equals method has been overridden to check equality on the integer instance variable

Answer (score 4):

Try this, [conditional Operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html)

```
System.out.println((o1.equals(o2) ? "Objects are equal": "Objects are not equal"));
```

Because your code is not a statement.

Answer (score 4):

That's called a [ternary operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). You cannot have statements in it.

But you can have expressions.

```
String output = o1.equals(o2) ? "Objects are equal":"Objects are not equal";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your code this way

```
System.out.println((o1.equals(o2) ? "Objects are equal" : "Objects are not equal"));
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Java Language Spec, under "Conditional Operator" -

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.

Since `println` is a void method, your second and third operand expressions meet this criterion.  As for why it works this way - that's just the way Java is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work

```
System.out.println(o1.equals(o2) ? "Objects are equal": "Objects are not equal");
```